# Examples of manipulating a 3d model inside an aframe photosphere

Tags: aframe, gltf, 3d-model

I want a gltf model inside a photosphere to behave like in aframe-model-viewer - you can "grab" it with mouse or controllers and rotate it in all axes, and zoom it. But when "not grabbing" or rotating away from the model for the photosphere to behave as normal.

So the model-viewer behaviour only occurs when interacting with the model in vr, mobile and desktop browser - it’s a gltf you can manipulate within a photosphere with the camera fixed to the centre of the sphere. Is that possible, and if it is do you know of any examples I can look at?

I've tried adding the model-viewer component into a photosphere scene, but the scene doesn't load, no errors.

Comment: Welcome! I recommend sharing code otherwise it will be hard for people to help. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great. Best of luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks Diego. Adding a sky to model-viewer and commenting out the background in model-viewer.js does get the scene to load. [https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fluorescent-playful-wizard](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fluorescent-playful-wizard)

I'd like to be able to scroll/look around the room, then look back at the model and grab it with mouse or controllers to rotate and zoom it. Do you know of any components or examples that would make that possible?